# How to create a snapshot view to certain baseline in a stream in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I'm using CC project explorer and when I right-click the stream I don't have possibility to choose the baseline. If I try to change the baseline on already existing snapshot CC says that I can't rebase on a baseline created in the same stream.

Comment: Just to be sure: when you say "when I right-click the stream I don't have possibility to choose the baseline", you try to access to what entry in the contextual menu on the stream?

Comment: Sorry for inaccuracies, I right-clicked the snapshot view's directory in windows explorer, chose ClearCase -> Properties of view -> Configuration -> chose newer baseline and tried to apply the changes.

Comment: Just completed my answer with a second way to access the content of a baseline, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to change the baseline on already existing snapshot CC says that I can't rebase on a baseline created in the some stream.

That is normal. It means some work (checkouts/checkins) have been done since the choice of the foundation baseline.

If you need to see (as in "just look, read-only access"), you can create another project with just one stream. On that empty stream, you will be able to select whatever baseline you need (as long as the associated component is non-modifiable, you will also be able to change that baseline).
Then you create your snapshot view referencing that new "consultation" stream.

The bottom line is that you cannot consult old baselines of a component on a stream where that same component is modifiable (and has been modified)

---

Another way to quickly consult the content of a Baseline is:

- through dynamic view (because you skip the "update" -- loading of files -- entirely
- more specifically a *base* dynamic view -- which does not reference any UCM stream.

in this dynamic view, you simply add a selection rule on your config spec:

```
element * MY_BASELINE_X.Y.Z
```

And here you go: instant access.
You will not be able to do any checkouts because ClearCase will detect those files are part of a UCM component.
But you will be able to:

- explorer the files
- edit the config spec and replace the baseline by any other baselines.

2 warnings:

- use the complete name of the baseline, not its title
- mount the correct vob (in a dynamic view, if no vob is mounted, you will not see one file!)

Comment: Is there really no other way to get read-only contents of same baseline than create a new project?

Comment: @VonC how can I tell what the full name of a baseline is? And what do you mean by "mount the vob"?

Comment: @AmirRachum mount: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12390081/6309, full baseline name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309 (also used in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1597297/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10233934/6309)