# do any one have batch file to apply and create label or base line in clearcase

Tags: batch-file, clearcase

here i need a batch file which can apply and create label or base line to the versioned elements in clear-case project, please provide me if any one have this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a (UCM) baseline, you do not need to create the label first.

Simply go within your view and put a baseline:

```
cd m:\myView\myVob\myRootComponent
cleartool mkbl -c "my comment" MY_BASELINE_LABEL
```

It will apply a label on all checked-in files of said UCM component.
Actually, it will apply several labels, one for each writable components of a UCM project:

- `MY_BASELINE_LABEL` for writable component 1
- `MY_BASELINE_LABEL.xyzz` for writable component 2
- `MY_BASELINE_LABEL.zyxx` for writable component 1

(it creates separate labels with the same 'title' (`MY_BASELINE_LABEL`) but different ids (- `MY_BASELINE_LABEL.xxxx`)

If your view references a UCM stream, that will "apply and create label or base line to the versioned elements in clear-case project", as you put it.
Put those commands in a batch and you have it.