# ClearCase: Version-extended pathname in a baseline

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

Is it possible to obtain the version-extended pathname of an element that belongs to a baseline?

For example, if I have a file name `/vobs/myproj/mydir/myfile.txt` and a baseline `bl_rc11` in a UCM project, is there a `cleartool` subcommand that will retun the version-extended pathname of `/vobs/myproj/mydir/myfile.txt` that belongs to `bl_rc11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print the extended pathname of any `myfile.txt` with the right baseline

```
cleartool find . -name 'myfile.txt' -version 'lbtype_sub(bl_rc11)' –print
```

But that supposes that:

- `bl_rc11` is a full baseline (see "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca/9696988#9696988)")
- `bl_rc11` is the ID of the baseline, not just its name (its ID could actually be `bl_rc11.xxxx`)

Another way would be to use [`cleartool diffbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm):

```
cleartool diffbl -pred -ver bl_rc11@\aPVob
```

But that will only list the delta between `bl_rc11` and its previous baseline, so even an incremental baseline would still generate a label on the version, meaning the cleartool find still works.