# ClearCase UCM - How to get only latest versions from latest baseline

Tags: clearcase

How to get only latest versions from latest baseline -

For example, First time in ClearCase, developers check in for the first time, we would have a.zip, b.zip ; ClearCase does the incremental baseline baseline_1.  Then the build tool comes in, does it gets artifact..and deploy it - everything looks good.

Second time in ClearCase, they check in c.zip and d.zip ; ClearCase does an incremental baseline again baseline_2... now how can I get the ClearCase snapshot view to only present the new files  (c.zip and d.zip) so the buil tool can only get the latest files (or last baseline)

This will go on and on and on.. so baseline will change each time.. so would the file.... and the date will not work since we don;t know the schedule or cycle.  The files name can also change from *.zip to whatever...

Answer (score 0):

A baseline references *all* the files of a component, even if it is incremental.

Using an incremental baseline in a non-UCM snapshot view wouldn't work, because it applies a label only on the elements which are changing (which means the *parent* directories might not have that label, because they haven't changed, which results in a config spec incapable of selecting the changed files, since said parent directory isn't even selected).

If you are after a view able to show all the latest files, what you can do is:

- a sub-stream `ST` to stream `S` which produce those baselines
- a rebase of `ST` with the [latest baseline from `S`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309):
  `cleartool lsbl -fmt "%[latest_bls]p" -component C -stream S`
- a [diffbl with the previous baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586531/6309), in order to get all the new versions

But you also can:

- list only the changed/new files:
  `cleartool diffbl -pred -ver latestBl@\aPVob`
- access those files through a dynamic view [with the extended pathnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904) returned by the `diffbl -pred  -ver` command.

That would allow to list/access only the new/changed versions between '`latestBl`' and its previous baseline (with `latestBl` obtained from the `lsbl` command shown above).

Comment: Thank you... just for clarification, the snapshot view is base UCM snapshot view.  I need to do this in an "automate" fashion (ie, this will be driven by another tool that only wants to pick up the last changes files from the last baseline).  

Can you suggest a way to do this without having to manually enter the previous baseline name.. and then able to  pick up only the changes files to copy to another directory?
Much appreciate !

Comment: @FFIC_UCM you don't have to enter the previous baseline name: that is what the option `-pred` is for. You will get only the new or changed files.