# Snapshot from old baseline

Tags: clearcase-ucm

Can I create a snapshot view with an old baseline without creating a new stream from the source stream?   I have been creating a child stream and pointing it to the old baseline; then making a snapshot of the newly created stream with the old baseline.
Not really a big deal just curious if there is another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the baseline is a *full* baseline, then yes, you can create a *base* snapshot view with a config spec like:

```
 element * CHECKEDOUT
 element /Vob/Component/... YourBaselineId
 element * /main/0
```

See "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca/9696988#9696988)" to know more about the importance of using a full baseline for *base* ClearCase views.

Otherwise, your method (`sub-stream`, `rebase`, `mkview`) is the standard one, creating an UCM view based on the configuration of the sub-stream.