# How to rename member baseline? Is it acceptable practice?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I have applied baseline for a component via cleartool. (we are using clearcase UCM).

I mistakenly put the wrong baseline name and i am unable to apply another one as it says no changes were done.

How to rename the baseline name in UCM ? (I tried via GUI but not finding a way).

If cleartool rmname can be used, can some one put an example how to do that? i did not find one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Renaming a Baseline does not change the label type name](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21251401)", you can rename a baseline through the CLI) but you need to rename the assiciated lbtype as well, for ClearCase 7.0 and before (7.1 and 8, you can just rename the baseline, it should take care of the lbtype. If not, see below).

```
cleartool rename baseline:<old baseline name>@\<component vob tag> baseline:<new baseline name>@\<component vob tag>
```

Check if the lbtype is renamed by doing a:
`cleartool descr -l baseline:<new baseline name>@\<component vob tag>`.

> ClearCase does not rename the `lbtype` automatically when a baseline is renamed because the `lbtype` is used as a version selector in every view that is attached to a stream using this baseline (as illustrated in `[IBM technote swg1IC41518][2]`).
>   If a UCM baseline lbtype is also renamed, it is necessary to run '`cleartool chstream -gen stream:<stream@pvob>`' for every stream using this baseline.
>   It is then necessary to run '`cleartool setcs -stream`' within every view associated to the stream.
>   Since it cannot be guaranteed that every view is available to the system that is renaming a UCM lbtype, this cannot be automated.

```
 cleartool rename lbtype:<old baseline name>@\<component vob tag> lbtype:<new baseline name>@\<component vob tag>
```

---

In short, it is possible but not trivial to rename a baseline for CC7.0 and before: it is an UCM object which is assosiated (through an hyperlink) to the lbtype used to create the label on all the elements which have changed (incremental baseline), or all the elements of the component (even those which haven't changed since the last baseline: full baseline, see "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca/9696988#9696988)")

You need to rename both (baseline and `lbtype`).

---

It is an acceptable practice since its *content* doesn't change.
However, you would need to propagate and communicate the new baseline name along your release management process.

Comment: I need to rename some baselines and I ran the this from CLI cleartool rename baseline:<old baseline name>@\<component vob tag> baseline:<new baseline name>@\<component vob tag>
we have 7.1.2 version of clearcase and the labeltype didn't change. Do I still need to change the lbtype?

Comment: @knm in that case, yes: but do change it in the vob *and* in the pvob.

Comment: Thanks! If I don't change the lbtype, does it matter or will I have problem. Since I am renaming the older one.

Comment: @knm I would change to have consistency between the names of the different object involves. An UCM baseline "guard" the associate lbtype, so it is important for them to keep a similar name.