# Clearcase configspec for view based on composite baseline

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

i am working on some scripts to migrate to git. I want to make a view based on a composite baseline to commit that data. I have several baselines to 'checkout'
Normal baselines I do with:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * baseline -nocheckout
element * /main/0 -ucm -nocheckout 

load /vobs/[component1]
load /vobs/[component2]
load /vobs/[component3]
```

But when the baseline is a composite the view stays empty...

What can I do?

Regards,

jr00n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that a composite baseline is a metalabel: when used in a base ClearCase view, it doesn't select any files, since its role is to group normal baselines.

If you can use an UCM view (based on a dedicated UCM project), that would be easier because:

- your composite baseline would select the right file (in that it would build the right config spec with all the grouped baselines in it)
- your normal baselines would select the right files (which is not always the case in a normal base ClearCase view, when the baseline isn't a [full one, but an incremental one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309))

So my advice: use a (dynamic) UCM view based on an Integration  stream, where you can rebase UCM baselines at will.

Comment: Thanks VonC, if i want to make a git commit of all the components where the composite baseline is based on, I have to: 1. Find the baselines the composite is made of. 2. Per baseline find the components of that baseline. 3. Make a view based on that basine and component. 4. Add the view to the git stage (git add) 5. Repeat step 3 and 4 6. Commit in git

Comment: @jr00n no, if your view is an UCM one, all you need to do is to rebase that composite baseline. The composite baseline will have added the right baselines in the config spec, which will have all the information you need.