# Clearcase ucm child stream missing files

Tags: stream, clearcase

We have integration stream xxx,I made baseline for this stream , added it as recommended baseline.
Based on this stream, I created child stream yyy.
For unknown reasons not all files of the component was not propagated to child stream yyy but do exist on the integration
We tried to update baselines, tried to rebase, but without any effect.
We tried even to create a new child stream and to create a new baseline on the integration stream but without any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that those files are:

- actually added to source control (do they have a version tree)
- labelled by the recommended baseline (make sure you promote that baseline to a [full one, not an incremental one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309))

Comment: files are under source control


How to check that files are labelled by the recommended baseline ?

Comment: @user3544428 simply by displaying their version tree. But make sure the baseline is a full one (as explained in the link in my answer)

Comment: we have listed vtree of files but they are not labelled by the baseline, can you please provide us with the procedure ?

Comment: @user3544428 first check if your baseline is a full one (cf my link)

Comment: when making baseline, we have choose its type to be Full not incremenetal, but we need a procedure how to apply this baseline to be a label to the files

Comment: @user3544428 no procedure needed: a full baseline will apply baseline to *all* files of a component. Could you check the config spec of your integration view you used for setting a new full baseline? The config spec, I supose, must not select the files where you don't see the label.

Comment: setting into integration view, I can see these files and create a new baseline with type Full in the integration stream and recommend this baseline, however when we rebase the child stream to this baseline some of these files doesn't exist

Comment: @user3544428 in that same integration view, once you have created a full baseline, do you see the label of that baseline applied on one version of the problematic file? (by opening the vtree of that file in that integration view)

Comment: @user3544428 so that is the issue right there. Can you check what a `cleartool ls` returns, when done in the parent folder of the file (which has no label), in that integration view?

Comment: It list the full path of each file as long as with the rule

Comment: I am thoinking of a procedure but actually i don't know if it is applicable in a production, it is the same as we first add a mofiable component to a project, the procedure willm be as follows:

Comment: 1.setting into the integration view     2.apply label to all versions of files/dir in the component that are visible to this view      3.Import this label as baseline from project explorer     4.recommend this baseline     5.rebase the child stream from this baseline

Comment: do you think that the above procedure will be appplicable and won't impact anything?

Comment: @user3544428 yes, but putting a full baseline should avoid the import step. Actually, that is a good point: is your component modifiable in your integration stream where you put that baseline?

Comment: @user3544428 the thing is: if there was **no modification** since the last baseline, any new baseline (even full) won't put a single label on a single file on that modifiable component. Can you try again to put a new full baseline, after purposefully checkout/checkin a file of that component?

Comment: Yes, we have already tried to modify one element before creating the new full baseline but with no help.

Comment: @user3544428 that is strange. The `cleartool ls` I requested a few comments before would help (to see what config spec selection rule is applied)

Comment: can this workaround help in the current issue? 1.setting into the integration view 2.apply label to all versions of files/dir in the component that are visible to this view 3.Import this label as baseline from project explorer 4.recommend this baseline 5.rebase the child stream from this baseline

Comment: @user3544428 you can try, but as long as we don't understand why a full baseline doesn't apply itself to a specific file, that won't be very useful. Hence my `cleartool ls` request.