# Mounting Target Machine (or Server) to Clearcase VOB

Tags: clearcase

I have read on IBM's Rational ClearCase manual that there is a  [ct mount](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm.) command, but I believe this is only to [mount a VOB](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_use_dyn_views.htm)  from the VOB server once you've entered the ClearCase environment.

I am trying to determine if I can mount my target machine to my personal ClearCase view. For example, I would ideally enter the following mount command on my target machine:

> mount -t nfs [server_of_view]:/some/vob/dir /local/dir/of/target/machine

Is it possible to perform a unix mount to a ClearCase view? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mount` and [`cleartool mount`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm) are two different commands.

The latter is for accessing a vob from a dynamic view (and is not used at all for snapshot views).

The former would enable you to access a snapshot view, and you wouldn't be able to checkout in it.

Comment: But is it possible to access the snapshot view from an remote machine? The snapshot view appears to be under a "/clearlib" directory and when I do a "df ." I get "[server]:/vol/vol2/VS01/myvob.vbs". I'm not sure how to point to the clearcase view from here.

Comment: '`vbs`' means *vob* storage, and has nothing to do with a view. A snapshot view is loaded on the hard drive, so follows the same rules than the rest of the filesystem. If you mount any external path within your snapshot view, you will be able to use said snapshot view. To be sure you are talking about a snapshot view, goes within /clearlib and type: `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`. You should see if it is a snapshot or dynamic view.

Comment: Ok, I used your suggested command and it turns out my view was _dynamic and not static_. From there I created a view using [ct mkview -snapshot](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm). The trickier part was editing the config spec with `ct edcs`. I used `"cleartool describe vob:."` in my dynamic view to figure out my vob path and files loaded as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake88 You are welcomed. You could have used also `ct catcs` in your first view in order to make the same config spec in the second view (plus the load rules)